# IBM Worklight - Mac - "'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined"

Tags: macos, environment-variables, blackberry-10, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working to set up the BlackBerry 10 environment on IBM worklight on Mac OS X. I'm pretty sure that I correctly added the environment variable for the WebWorks SDK.

I added these 2 lines in these 2 files: .profile, .bash_profile:

```
export WEBWORKS_HOME=/Developer/SDKs/Research\ In\ Motion/BlackBerry\ 10\ WebWorks\ SDK\ 1.0.4.11<br>
export PATH=$PATH:$WEBWORKS_HOME
```

But I'm still getting this error during the build:

> blackberry10 build failed: The 'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me.

1. Install the latest BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK from this location: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/?os=mac#blackberry10

   As I was unable/unsure how to work with spaces in the variable path (there is a way to do so, I just haven't figured it out), I renamed the path folders:

   **From:** `/Developer/SDKs/Research In Motion/BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11`

   **To:** `/Developer/SDKs/RIM/1.0.4.11`
2. Open the Terminal application and

   - Type: `sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf`
   - Press 'i' to enter edit mode
   - Type: `setenv WEBWORKS_HOME /Developer/SDKs/RIM/1.0.4.11`
   - Press 'ESC' and type: `:wq` to save and quit VI
   - Restart the computer

Comment: It doesn't work with the first path may be because of the space characters, even I made "\" before each space. After that I changed the path without space characters and it works. Thank you very much