# IBM Worklight 6.0 - "WebWorks SDK source file was not found" error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am using Worklight 6 on Mac OS, and I installed WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5.

I have got some issues with WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable, that I fixed after reading [IBM Worklight - Mac - "'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260481/ibm-worklight-mac-webworks-home-environment-variable-is-undefined)

Now I am having the error

> WebWorks SDK source file was not found. Make sure to set it in
>   application-decsriptor.xml: Replace it with path to WebWorks SDK

When I try to build the Blackberry app.

When I check my application descriptor, I only see

```
<blackberry10 version="1.0"/>
```

Should I add something to Blackberry app in the application descriptor? or what shall I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed the **wrong** SDK.

- For BlackBerry 6 and 7, use: https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/downloads/?os=mac#smartphones
- For BlackBerry 10, use: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/?os=mac#blackberry10

Make sure that the WEBWORKS_HOME variable path points to that of the BlackBerry 10 SDK.