# IBM Worklight - How to resolve "WebWorks SDK source file was not found" error?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-webworks

I am using Worklight 6 on Windows 7.

I've installed the WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry and also set the environment path for the WebWorks SDK.

When trying to build my application (that has the blackberry10 environment) the following error is shown:

> W: WebWorks SDK source file was not found. Make sure to set it in
>   application-decsriptor.xml: Replace it with path to WebWorks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the BB10 SDK has got nothing to do with `application-descriptor.xml` file so I don't quite understand why would it complain about it *there*.

Here is a question with this same error; The problem in this case was about using an incorrect SDK version:
[IBM Worklight 6.0 - "WebWorks SDK source file was not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401232/ibm-worklight-6-0-webworks-sdk-source-file-was-not-found-error)

- For BlackBerry 6 and 7, use: https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/downloads/?os=mac#smartphones
- For BlackBerry 10, use: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/?os=mac#blackberry10

Also note that Worklight does not officially support BB10 WebWorks SDK **2.0 beta**.
So make sure to use the previous version ([1.0.4.11 - direct download link](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/fetch/BB10-WebWorks-SDK_1.0.4.11.exe)), perhaps it will help in solving this.

I would also make sure that your WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable indeed points to the correct location; In my - working - setup it points to: `C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11`