# Setup Blackberry10 Environment on Mac

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I'm building Hybrid application on Worklight using Eclipse.

I have downloaded BB10 sdks and followed the steps mentioned in previous question 
([IBM Worklight - Mac - "'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260481/ibm-worklight-mac-webworks-home-environment-variable-is-undefined))

However, I'm still facing this issue when I build the project using eclipse on Mac:

blackberry10 build failed: the 'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is not defined. Add an environment variable named 'WEBWORKS_HOME' pointing to the WebWorks SDK root folder.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `echo $WEBWORKS_HOME` in a terminal give you?

Comment: I'm getting this (/Applications/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15) even I have set my env as the link I have provided.

Comment: Then you are **not** following my explanation in the link from your question (even though you say you are...). Follow it. Remove the spaces and follow the steps exactly. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I've taken:

1. I've installed the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK v1.x to:

   > /Users/idanadar/Documents/MobileFirst/Setup/BlackBerry/10/SDK1.0.4.11

   - For BlackBerry WebWorks SDK v2.x, please make sure to also [read this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en)
2. I then used the [EnvPane](http://diaryproducts.net/EnvPane) application to create a "WEBWORKS_HOME" variable pointing to the above path.
3. After restarting Eclipse, I've created a new project & application, and successfuly added the BlackBerry 10 environment it.